# get count from sql query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such query

```
SELECT `id`
FROM (`TABLE`)
WHERE date(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) >= '2013-10-28'
GROUP BY `last`
ORDER BY `id_s` DESC
```

the result is:

> | id |
>
> 9
> 1
> 1
> 9
> 50
> 3
> 1

My question is how to count how many times repeating number 9 in result?

So, the final result must be one row with number 2

Somebody have idea how possible to do it?

Comment: Please provide information about the table structure and some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the result set that you already have, select id=9 from it and count the rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  --your current query here
) WHERE `id`=9
GROUP BY `id`
```

There might be a better way of doing this in your situation, but without knowing your table structure and maybe seeing some example data, this is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT count(distinct last)
FROM (TABLE)
WHERE date(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) >= '2013-10-28' AND
      id = 9 ;
```

I'm not sure what the `group by` really does, so it might be sufficient to do:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (TABLE)
WHERE date(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) >= '2013-10-28' AND
      id = 9 ;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly will not work becouse key in this query is "ORDER BY id_s"

Comment: The best way will if is possible to get this 9 after executed this query?

Comment: I am totally missing something.  The `order by` has nothing to do with how many times the value "9" appears.